# Google Places Autocomplete with angular options not working

Tags: angular, google-places-api

I'm using the ngx-google-place-autocomplete component in an angular project, mostly it's working fine, but i have a couple of issues here:

Here is my options setup.

```
public options: Options  ={
    bounds: undefined, fields: ["address_component"], strictBounds: false,
    types: ['geocode','route'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'gb'}
  };
```

Issue 1:

The first issue is that if i include "address_component" in the fields array, because i don't need all the rest of the data, the address change event never fires, but if i remove it then it works fine. Just wondering if this is a component bug or a google api bug?

Issue 2:

No matter what settings i put in "types" the results never come up with all the properties on a street. So if i search a uk postcode i would have expected all the houses on that street to show up, but instead it just gives the street name, town and county. I would like to be able to have the user select a specific address for the postcode. Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem as your issue 1:
I am not sure if it's the library (most probably it is, I don't think there is a bug in the google api), but I needed to include `'place_id'` into my fields, otherwise the `(onAddressChange)` method wouldn't fire.

So if you put `fields: ["address_component", "place_id"]` it should work.

Edit: This has been fixed in the newest version of the library

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this same issue, try using the constructor.

```
options: Options = new Options({
  bounds: undefined, fields: ["address_component"], strictBounds: false,
  types: ['geocode','route'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: 'gb'}
});
```

Remember to import `Options` using `import { Options } from 'ngx-google-places-autocomplete/objects/options/options';`